# Why doesn't the DOM style node show styles applied by a style sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a jsfiddle here -http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/R3z2j/2/ - where I've applied a red background to the body in a style sheet, but when I look at the body's style node in the DOM with

```
style = document.body.style;
bgclr = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
```

there's nothing there for background color.

Thanks

Comment: [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) or [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231.aspx) (IE8 and older). [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) "*represents the element's `style` attribute*," or the element's inline styles, not those it inherits.

Comment: DOM properties that have the same name as DOM attributes mostly reflect the same values. So the DOM style object represents the values applied through the style attribute or set by assigning to properties of the style object.

Comment: So how can JavaScript determine what color an element is when the color was set by a style sheet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment...

[`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) "*represents the element's style attribute*," or the element's own styles as from the `style` attribute or direct manipulation.

To get the styles the element is actually using (including inherited), you can use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) in [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle) (optionally with [`getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)) or [`element.currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231.aspx) in oldIE:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('background-color')

document.body.currentStyle.backgroundColor
```

Or, since you're using jQuery, you can also use [`.css(propertyName)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1):

```
$(document.body).css('background-color');
```

Comment: The style object also represents values set directly on style properties, not just those set through the attribute (e.g. *element.style.color*).

Comment: @RobG Thought "*or the element's own, inline styles*" would cover that. Not so much? Though, in many current browsers, changes to `element.style` are reflected in the attribute.

Comment: The term "inline styles" refers to those in the markup, so it doesn't cover values set by *setAttribute* or by style object properties.