# javascript style.left returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, return, undefined

I have set my css left selector with value of 20%, but I get **undefined**??

my code:

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/ouhtk

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#item1").click(function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("item1").style.left.value);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `value` that is a error

```
  $("#item1").click(function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("item1").style.left);
  });
```

In this case the value is `''` and not `undefined`

If you wan't the computed value you would do this

```
  $("#item1").click(function(){
     var element = document.getElementById("item1");
     console.log( window.getComputedStyle( element ).left );
  });
```

Or with `jQuery`

```
  $("#item1").click(function(){
     console.log( $(this).css('left') );
  });
```

if you want to calculate the percentage then you can do this

```
  $("#item1").click(function(){
     var parent = $(this).parent().width();
     console.log( 100 * $(this).width() / parent );

  });
```

Comment: but still my left value is 20%, why do I get empty string instead?

Comment: You can't get the `20%` on the fly

Answer (score 2):

`element.style` only contains inline styles or those applied directly to that element.

To get computed styles, including those inherited from stylesheets, you can use jQuery's [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$('#item1').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).css('left'));
});
```

Or, for a native solution, see [Why doesn't the DOM style node show styles applied by a style sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17645275).